# Default function parameter ordering

Tags: coffeescript

Reading through [this](http://jashkenas.github.com/coffee-script/), I came to the bit on default values for function arguments:

```
fill = (container, liquid = "coffee") ->
  "Filling the #{container} with #{liquid}..."
```

That's neat, but then I tried this:

```
fill = (container="mug", liquid = "coffee") ->
  "Filling the #{container} with #{liquid}..."

alert fill(liquid="juice")
```

and got the unexpected alert with `"Filling the juice with coffee..."`. So then I tried this:

```
fill = (container="mug", liquid = "coffee") ->
  "Filling the #{container} with #{liquid}..."

alert fill(null, "juice")
```

and it worked. It's not pretty though. Is there a better way, or is this the idiomatic way to do this?

Comment: looks ugly or tastes funny, tough call

Answer (score 85, accepted):

```
fill = ({container, liquid} = {}) ->
     container ?= "mug"
     liquid ?= "coffee"

     "Filling the #{container} with #{liquid}..."

alert fill(liquid: "juice", container: "glass")
alert fill()
```

```
fill = (quantity="500 mL", {container, liquid} = {}) ->
     container ?= "mug"
     liquid ?= "coffee"

     "Filling the #{container} with #{quantity} of #{liquid}..."

alert fill("1L", liquid: "juice", container: "glass")
alert fill()
alert fill "1L"
alert fill "1L", liquid: "water"
```

Comment: This is definitely the canonical way to do it. There's no way for CoffeeScript to add named arguments to JavaScript directly, but its pattern-matching object syntax is the next best thing. Regrettably, pattern-matching can't be combined with default values at this time, so Jeremy's proposal is as succinct as you can get.

Comment: Just wanted to say how helpful I found this answer, thanks. +1

Comment: It should be `fill = ({container, liquid} = {}) -> ...` if you want to be able to call the function without any parameters, `fill()`. Also, you can use normal default values for positional parameters: `fill = (quantity="500 ml", {container, liquid} = {}) -> ...` can be called `fill()`, `fill "1L"` or with any combination of the named parameters, e.g. `fill "1L", liquid: "juice"`.

Comment: @JulianD. 's comment should be added to the answer! Would have saved me a lot of time.

Answer (score 8):

Amir and Jeremy already have this. As they point out, `container="mug"` in a function's argument list is really just shorthand for `container ?= "mug"` in the function body.

Let me just add that when calling functions,

```
fill(liquid="juice")
```

means the same thing as in JavaScript: First, assign the value `"juice"` to the `liquid` variable; then pass `liquid` along to `fill`. CoffeeScript doesn't do anything special here, and `liquid` has the same scope in that situation as it would outside of the function call.

By the way, I've suggested that the default argument syntax should be made more powerful by allowing arguments to be skipped (e.g. `(first, middle ?= null, last) ->` would assign values to `first` and `last` if only two arguments were passed), and that the `?=` syntax should be used rather than `=`. You might want to express support for that proposal here: [issue 1091](https://github.com/jashkenas/coffee-script/issues/1091).

Comment: I think `optional function arguments` work well in frameworks like jQuery but they diminish readability a bit. If there are tons of functions that use this style in some piece of code, I might have to look at each function definition to have a feeling of what the parameters are. For example: `animate 100, ->` vs `animate {delay:100}, ->`.  Just so you can also do `animate ->`.

Comment: Thanks, I hadn't realized that was just assignment. Too much Python, probably.

Answer (score 5):

Currently, there's no way to call with named arguments.  It would require knowing the arguments (names, positions, and/or default values) at the calling site, which is not always feasible in javascript/coffeescript.

Instead if you have many arguments and you want to name them and have default values, you could do something like this:

```
fill = (opts = {}) ->
    opts.container ?= "mug"
    opts.liquid ?= "coffee"
    "Filling the #{opts.container} with #{opts.liquid}..."

alert fill
    liquid:"juice"
    container:"cup"

alert fill
    liquid:"juice"

alert fill()
```