# What's a concise way to have defaults for the fields of an optional parameter in CoffeeScript?

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

I've got a function with this signature:

```
createUiLabel = (text, fontProperties) ->
```

I want fontProperties to be optional and if undefined, default to something like this:

```
{
  size: defaultSize
  family: defaultFamily
  color: defaultColor
}
```

I know I can achieve this with destructuring like this:

```
createUiLabel = (text, fontProperties = {
  size: defaultSize
  family: defaultFamily
  color: defaultColor
}) ->
```

But it would be really convenient to be able to call this function like this:

```
createUiLabel("foo", {size: 14})
```

And have the `color` and `family` still use the defaults.  But it seems that passing in this object is overriding the other properties so `color` and `family` become undefined.  It's pretty annoying from the outside to have to define these other properties when you only want to change one.  How can I easily implement the function so that the preceding call will give me a default value for `color` and `family`?

This seems similar to [Most concise way to assign a value from a variable only if it exists in CoffeeScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11059788/most-concise-way-to-assign-a-value-from-a-variable-only-if-it-exists-in-coffeesc) The difference is there's an optional object in between that I'm trying to extract optional fields out of.

Comment: Check out [underscores defaults method](http://underscorejs.org/#defaults), that does exactly what you are asking for here.

Comment: @KyleNeedham nice.  In the end I'll use this.  Not sure what to do next with this question.  Should I delete it?  Should I still wait for someone to answer in terms of coffeescript?  Or should I accept your answer in terms of underscore even though it's not in coffeescript terms?

Comment: You could answer your own question with how you solved it, or wait and see if a better solution comes up.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Default function parameter ordering](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5238398/default-function-parameter-ordering)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd go with explicit compound assignments using the existential [operator](http://coffeescript.org/#operators) on an empty default-value:

```
createUiLabel = (text, fontProperties = {}) ->
    fontProperties.size ?= defaultSize
    fontProperties.color ?= defaultColor
    fontProperties.family ?= defaultFamily
    …
```

Comment: Nice, thanks a lot.  In the end I think i'll use underscore/lodash's `_.default` but I'm glad to know this.